# Listbox Control (SelectionMode = Multiple) dosen't load all data in sql-server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a table 'TheLoai' and I want to load it from SQL-Server but it didn't work effectively.

[image]

[image]

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                getData();
            }
        }

        public void getData()
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-R8LG380\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PHIM;Integrated Security=True");

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from TheLoai", conn);
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader dtr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            lst_TheLoai.DataSource = dtr;
            lst_TheLoai.DataTextField = "TenTL";
            lst_TheLoai.DataValueField = "MaTL";
            lst_TheLoai.DataBind();
            conn.Close();

        }
```

Comment: So two questions: If you set the selectionmode to Single does it act differently. And if you set the Rows property of the listbox to say 6, does it show all the rows?

Comment: @JM_ it is not working :<

Comment: What does that mean? Do you get an error? does it only show 4 rows? please elaborate

Comment: @JM_ it does not occur error and only 4 lines appear